# do seam and weld in java 7 obsolete Spring? Is it still worth learning Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Ive heard bits and pieces about Seam and Weld in Java 7, and am trying to figure out how they relate to Spring. Any pointers to good references appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is much more than dependency injection, although DI is at its core and many people receive no more of it.

I worked with both Seam and Spring and found a surprising number of things possible in one, but not the other. They do not cover entirely the same area. Where they do, they are both viable alternatives. Spring is actively maintained. I cannot see it die anytime soon. That was the answer to your question heading.

To address the body of your question: Sorry. I’d be interested in a succinct but in-depth comparison as well.

Answer (score 2):

Spring might some day become obsolete for new projects. Still, in the last X years almost every Java EE project was done with atleast a bit of Spring technology (in my experience), so there is **a lot** of software out there running Spring ( I am currently on a project which uses Spring 2 ) and that isn't going to change in the near future. Corporation don't change a running system just because the new Y technology is out. (As all the COBOL software laying around painfully demonstrates)

So to directly awnser your question, I believe that Spring knowledge will remain a must for many years to come.

Answer (score 1):

No. As others have said Spring is more than DI and is established.

The reality is there are three entities competing (and in some cases working together) for more users/developers.

- VMware aka Springsource
- Redhat aka JBoss, Seam and Weld
- Oracle aka Glassfish

I would like to believe that each one of these companies doesn't have an agenda but the reality is they do and they want you to use their technology. You'll often see developers (*employees*) of each project vehemently trash the other project. Avoid this and make your own opinion by trying each.